# How to solve GWT compiler 2.5.0 exception

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

Cannot package GWT project with maven and Intellij IDEA. Help me please to resolve this problem. I have multi module structure. I've tried to clean all target.

My Maven gwt-compiler-plugin configuration:

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.5.0</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>compile</goal>
>                         <goal>generateAsync</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>                 <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
>                 <style>OBFUSCATED</style>
>                 <module>com.example.Gui</module>
>                 <force>true</force>
>                 <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss2048k</extraJvmArgs>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Error trace:

> ```
> [INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default) @ gui-localon ---
> [WARNING] Don't declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
> [INFO] Compiling module net.piqc.gui.gwt.localon.GuiLocalon
> [INFO] [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
> [INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Error constructing Java AST
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.translateException(GwtAstBuilder.java:2989)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.visit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1649)
> [INFO]    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:237)
> [INFO]    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:239)
> [INFO]    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1239)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:2948)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:124)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:247)
> [INFO]    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:718)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:248)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:463)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:388)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:373)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:246)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
> [INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram.createLocal(Lcom/google/gwt/dev/jjs/SourceInfo;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/dev/jjs/ast/JType;ZLcom/google/gwt/dev/jjs/ast/JMethodBody;)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/jjs/ast/JLocal;
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.createLocal(GwtAstBuilder.java:2079)
> [INFO]    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.visit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1646)
> [INFO]    ... 21 more
> [INFO]    [ERROR] at AbstractDataTable.java(124): JsArrayNumber timevalue = getValueTimevalue(rowIndex, columnIndex);
> [INFO]       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration
> ```

Comment: Did you try to declare the dependency `gwt-dev` as scope `provided`?

Comment: Can you switch to version 2.5.1? It looks like it is this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7789

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help me :(